# Utilizing EE Admin Action Log

Tags: admin, magento-enterprise, log

So, I'm building a custom module to allow admins to define some custom business logic. I have most of it worked out at this point but I would like to tap into the admin action log that is included in Magento Enterprise Edition.

Is there a helper or model that automatically picks up the current user information (ID, time, IP, etc) and just allows me to specify the unique-to-my-module info?

Answer (score 7):

You need to create a file called logging.xml in the `etc` folder of your module. where you should list your logged events. Take as example the logging.xml from the `Enterprise_Logging` module.
Should look something like this. Replace the markup with your own values:

```
<{entityCodeHere} translate="label">
    <label>{Entity Label here}</label>
    <expected_models>
        <{moduleName}__{entityName}/> <!-- replace the slash in the parameter you give to Mage::getModel() when instatiating the object with double underscore -->
    </expected_models>
    <actions>
        <adminhtml_{contrller}_{action}> <!-- or {module}_adminhtml_{contrller}_{action} . It depends on how the extension looks. It's basically the same as the layout handle for the page-->
            <action>{action}</action>
        </adminhtml_{contrller}_{action}>
     <!-- add as many actions as you want -->
    </actions>
</{entityCodeHere}>
```

I hope I didn't miss something. Anyway, this is the right direction.

Comment: Oh wow. I should've guessed it would be XML based lol. I'll try this out and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Important note here: `Enterprise_Logging` module logs events performed only with `adminhtml` route:

```
<controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_logging>
            <class>enterprise_logging/observer</class>
            <method>controllerPostdispatch</method>
        </enterprise_logging>
    </observers>
</controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml>
```

If you have admin controller with custom router, you need to add additional observer to you module to call `controllerPostdispatch` method.

For example, if you have router called *ordermanager*:

```
<controller_action_postdispatch_ordermanager>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_logging>
            <class>enterprise_logging/observer</class>
            <method>controllerPostdispatch</method>
        </enterprise_logging>
    </observers>
</controller_action_postdispatch_ordermanager>
```